# PHP Classes containing only constants

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

First of all: I tried to google it, but I mostly only found discussions about how to define arrays in constants and other unrelated information.

I have a question regarding a solution to make my code more readable (and pretty) that just occured to me. Basically I have most functions return a status code that indicates success or, in case something went wrong, an error code. For this, I made a class called "StatusCode" that contains only constants, like so:

```
<?php
class StatusCode {
  const success = 0;
  const badArgument = -1;
  const badQuery = -2;
  const outOfMana = -3; //Really just for demonstration purposes
  ...
}
```

The purpose is to make magic numbers disappear from my code and make it clear what went wrong without having to look for an explaination somewhere:

```
if (mana > 10) {
  //Do some magic
  return StatusCode::success;
}
else {
  //Oh god this is not good!
  return StatusCode::outOfMana;
}
```

It should also eliminate the possibility of accidently using duplicate error codes.
I'm pretty sure this adds a minor overhead to my application, but has made my code easier to understand in return. Is there some earth shattering reason not to do this? Maybe an even better way to go about it?

(I have avoided the `define(CONSTANT, "value")` approach because it seems less pretty and it's a hassle to write on my German keyboard :))

Comment: There's no reason why NOT to do what you did. As you said, it makes your code more readable. As for adding overhead, even if it's true it's entirely minimal overhead. As for better ways, there are variations to what you've done by using interfaces to define constants. TL;DR - what you did is good.

Comment: Completely agree with what @N.B. said. My only issue with this post is that it should be over at code review, not here ;)

Comment: In this tiny corner of coding style your choice is the absolute best there is. And when talking about style, one doesn't get to say "absolute best" very often. ;-) BTW, you might want to make this class `abstract` or `final` as an additional hint of how it's not supposed to be used. Unfortunately it cannot be both, which would seal the deal.

Comment: Thanks for the hint (and the praise ^^), it does indeed seem like a good idea to stop people from making an instance of that class, so I guess I'll go for `abstract`. It seems more unlikely someone will extend the class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Java and other languages this is a commonly used way to namespace constants to avoid naming collisions. See [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=2);

The way that I would implement such a class is like this"

```
// make this final so no one can extend it
final class Errors{
    const SUCCESS = 0;
    const BAD_ARGUMENT = -1;
    const BAD_QUERY = -2;
    const OUT_OF_MANA = -3;

    // make this private so noone can make one
    private function __construct(){
        // throw an exception if someone can get in here (I'm paranoid)
        throw new Exception("Can't get an instance of Errors");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of just making the constructor private instead of using abstract? Thanks, your example covers both "don't instantiate" and "don't extend".

Comment: Good answer as it also points out that constants should be all uppercase separated by underscores.
[PHP FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)
[ZEND Framework](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

Answer (score 1):

This has the advantage of namespacing and *grouping* constants. You can use reflection on that class to iterate over defined constants, which allows you, for example, to validate that a value is a value of a certain constant group (enabling a poor man's constant type hinting).

The disadvantage is that you're kind of abusing a class (though only slightly). Purists may not like that. Constants which are not used in the same class should be global constants; you can even namespace them into something like `\StatusCodes\SUCCESS` in PHP 5.3+.

The choice is yours, really.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an **static** class will solve your problem and avoid creating multiple instances of `StatusCode`

Namespaces can be used if you think your application can have multiple StatusCode classes but still the StatusCode will be static.

If you want to use singleton pattern this will work too

Choice is yours!

Comment: Actually I don't want any instance at all.

Comment: From class definition like this "class StatusCode" multiple instances can be done as so as memory management will be based on that, so better define static class StatusCode and use it as StatusCode::*

Comment: PHP doesn't support `static class Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface, so an instance cannot be created:

```php
interface StatusCode {
    public const success = 0;
    public const badArgument = -1;
    public const badQuery = -2;
    public const outOfMana = -3;
}
```